# "conn busy" error when executing update against result from query

Tags: postgresql, go, go-fiber

I want to select the data and at the same time the lastlogin data will change in current date and time.

This is my Code and the error is 2023/08/18 15:07:21 conn busy
I already try the update current date in many position and still the same of error. I already try to have more defer close and still the same of error. my connection in database is okay beacuse some of my codes is works and the Select is working but Update current date is not.

```golang
// SELECT MEMBER
func SearcMember(c *fiber.Ctx) error {

    var request Models.Request
    if err := c.BodyParser(&request); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    rows, err := DBConnection.GetDB().Query(ctx, "SELECT id, login, firstname, mi, lastname, email, passwd, institution, area, internet, level, lastlogin, region, loginToken, staffId, mobileNumber, userStat, isLogin FROM members WHERE login = $1 AND passwd = $2", request.Login, request.Password)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError).SendString("Internal Server Error")
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var Members []Models.SelectMembers

    for rows.Next() {
        var Member Models.SelectMembers
        var Institution sql.NullString
        var Area sql.NullString
        var Internet sql.NullString
        var Level sql.NullInt32
        var LastLogin sql.NullString
        var Region sql.NullInt32
        var LoginToken sql.NullString
        var StaffID sql.NullString
        var UserStatus sql.NullInt32
        var ISLogin sql.NullInt32

        err := rows.Scan(&Member.MembersID, &Member.LogIn, &Member.FullName.FirstName, &Member.FullName.MiddleName, &Member.FullName.LastName, &Member.Email, &Member.Password, &Institution, &Area, &Internet, &Level, &LastLogin, &Region, &LoginToken, &StaffID, &Member.MobileNumber, &UserStatus, &ISLogin)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        Member.Institution = Institution.String
        Member.Area = Area.String
        Member.Internet = Internet.String
        Member.Level = int(Level.Int32)
        Member.LastLogin = LastLogin.String
        Member.LoginToken = LoginToken.String
        Member.Region = int(Region.Int32)
        Member.StaffID = StaffID.String
        Member.UserStatus = int(UserStatus.Int32)
        Member.ISLogin = int(ISLogin.Int32)

        Member.Name = fmt.Sprintf("%s %s %s", Member.FullName.FirstName, Member.FullName.MiddleName, Member.FullName.LastName)
        Members = append(Members, Member)

        defer rows.Close()
        // Update the LastLogin field with the current date and time
        if LastLogin.Valid {
            currentTime := time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
            // Update the lastlogin field in the database
            _, updateErr := DBConnection.GetDB().Exec(ctx, "UPDATE members SET lastlogin = $1 WHERE id = $2", currentTime, Member.MembersID)
            log.Print("Nababasa")
            if updateErr != nil {
                log.Println(updateErr)
            }
        }
    }

    return c.Status(fiber.StatusCreated).JSON(Members)
}
```

and This is my database connection

```
package DBConnection

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
)

var db *pgx.Conn
var ctx = context.Background()

func InitDB() {

    conn, err := pgx.Connect(ctx, "postgres://postgres:12345@localhost:5432/crd_audit?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to connect to database: %v", err)
    }
    
    db = conn
}

func GetDB() *pgx.Conn {
    return db
}
```

I want to select the data and at the same time the lastlogin data will change in current date and time.

Comment: Please show us `DBConnection.GetDB()` (ideally provide a [minimal, **reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see how you are connecting). Note that the extra `defer rows.Close()` will not help (due to the `defer` this will run when the function returns; using `defer` in a loop is usually an error). If your query will only return one row (max) then use `QueryRow`.

Comment: package DBConnection

import (
 "context"
 "log"

 "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
)

var db *pgx.Conn
var ctx = context.Background()

func InitDB() {

 conn, err := pgx.Connect(ctx, "postgres://postgres:12345@localhost:5432/crd_audit?sslmode=disable")
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Unable to connect to database: %v", err)
 }
 
 db = conn
}

func GetDB() *pgx.Conn {
 return db
}

Answer (score 0):

As per the [PGX Docs](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/wiki/Getting-started-with-pgx#using-a-connection-pool):

> The *pgx.Conn returned by pgx.Connect() represents a single connection and is not concurrency safe. This is entirely appropriate for a simple command line example such as above.

So this is a single connection; you cannot run two commands simultaneously over a single connection. You are doing just that (hence the `conn busy` error) when you:

1. Run query to select data from `members`
2. For each result:

   1. `Exec` `UPDATE members` (this requires an additional connection)
3. Close initial `select` query

You could solve this by refactoring your code so that only a single connection is needed. There are a few ways of doing this but the simplest would be to use [`QueryRow`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx#Conn.QueryRow) (as I would expect that you will have database constraints that prevent duplicate `login` values because having duplicates would be bad!). Alternatively (in a situation where multiple results are needed) you could:

1. Run `select` on `members` and get all results (running `rows.Close()` when done).
2. Loop through the `Members` slice running the update (`UPDATE members`) for each.

**However** I don't recommend the above approach. This is because you appear (based on the use of `fibre`) to be writing a server and may need to process concurrent requests (e.g. you may receive two logon requests at the same time).

A better solution is to use a [connection pool](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/wiki/Getting-started-with-pgx#using-a-connection-pool). This will manage multiple database connections enabling you to run more than one query at a time (it's also safe to use concurrently unlike a `*pgx.Conn`).

This would look something like:

```
package DBConnection

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgxpool"
)

var db *pgxpool.Pool
var ctx = context.Background()

func InitDB() {
    dbpool, err := pgxpool.New(ctx, "postgres://postgres:12345@localhost:5432/crd_audit?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to connect to create pool: %v", err)
    }

    db = dbpool
}

func GetDB() *pgxpool.Pool {
    return db
}
```